# Integrated Screen goes blank with Dual-screen

Tags: hdmi

While I had the hdmi exit connected to my TV, I configured my **laptop screen** to be turned off. Now, everytime I connect the hdmi, my laptop screen goes blank and nothing appears on my TV. Can you help me?

Comment: I can't find the solution anywhere. Will I have to format? Is there a file I can delete and everything will come back to normal?

Comment: I just logged in as root and dual screen is working well. looks like there's a file I need to delete in my home folder.

Comment: You should post solution as answer and not as an edit

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know that.

Comment: @FRD You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. Please do that, else we'll have to write your answer as a Community wiki answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answered by OP in a comment and question:*

> I just logged in as root and dual screen is working well. looks like
>   there's a file I need to delete in my home folder. I solved it with `rm .config/monitors.xml`